# Javascript - dynamic multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been struggling with this for a day and I can't figure it out.  I've searched this site and can't find an answer or I'm not smart enough to figure it out from the answers that are there.  Here's what I am trying to do:-

I have an HTML table with peoples names and effort.  I have created a unique list of the names (in my option element) so I want to loop through the table and for each occurance of a name, add the effort to an array entry.  What I want to end up with is a small array of person name and total effort spent by them......I hope that makes sense.....

I only started using JS about 4 weeks ago so I apologize if it looks ugly:-

```
 var memArray=new Array(); //define an empty array.

    for(x=1;x<=opt.length-1;x++) { //loop through option element to get names 
        memArray[x]=[]; // add a second array (inner) to outer array
        memArray[x]=opt.options[x].value; //post value to first row of outer array
    }
    for(y=1;y<=obj.rows.length-2;y++){ //cycle through html table called obj
        for(z=1;z<=memArray.length-1;z++) { //for each row in table, cycle through outer array
            if(memArray[z]==obj.rows[y].cells[3].innerHTML) { //if the names match......
                memArray[z][0]=memArray[z][0]+obj.rows[y].cells[6].innerHTML; //grab the effort from the 6th table cell and add to inner array to get total....
                //alert(memArray[z]+' '+obj.rows[y].cells[6].innerHTML);
                }
        }
    }
    for(z=1;z<=memArray.length-1;z++) {
        alert(memArray[z][0]); //loop through array 
        }
```

When I try and read the value of the second array dimension, it is saying "undefined" - yet I am trying to add the sum of the effort for that person to that array element with "memArray[z][0]=memArray[z][0]+obj.rows[y].cells[6].innerHTML;"

I've created the problem in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nashleigh/D9a4q/)

- I pull the values from the option element and create my outer array
- I need to cycle through the table elements - for each occurance of a name, get the value from the second column and update the inner array with the sum (for that name).  So, "Name 1" should total 15 and "Name 2" should total 7.

Comment: Could you post an example of your array or, even better, add your code and HTML to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see it in action?

Comment: I highly recommend using the "[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)" or "[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)" functions if you don't need IE < 9 support. It will clean up your code a lot of make it easier to understand/debug.

Comment: It seems odd that you're reading your values directly from the HTML table. Assuming the table is being populated dynamically and not hard-coded HTML, you should have access to the data in a different way. Give more info and then we can help you with the loop.

Comment: I also noticed that all your loops are starting a index 1. Arrays start at index 0, so I'm unsure if this is intentional or not.

Comment: Pete - I need to use IE9 - unfortunately!  Loops starting at 1 are intentional because I am ignoring first entry the elements (they are blanks - intentionally also).

Comment: gotmikhail - page is built dynamically using php - it pulls the data and builds the HTML table.  As the user selects (checks) names, I want it to add up the effort or reduce it for that person.  I don't want to do page refreshes and database calls for that when all my data is there in the HTML and the client can process all this using javascript.  If I only knew how :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need - I would recommend you to use an Object (now Array) as a hash of values. In that case you'll get smth like dictionary (key-value collection) where key - name, value - anything (in you case - I think a string but also could be an array):

```
var hash = {};

for(var x = 1; x <= opt.length-1; x++) { //loop through option element to get names 
    hash[opt.options[x].value] = null; //if you need an array - hash[opt.options[x].value] = [];
}

for(var y = 1; y <= obj.rows.length-2; y++){ //cycle through html table called obj
    var name = obj.rows[y].cells[3].innerHTML;
    if (hash[name] !== undefined) { //if the given user is inside the hash
        hash[name] += obj.rows[y].cells[6].innerHTML;
    }
}

for(var name in hash) {
    alert(hash[name]);
}
```

**Note:** `innerHTML` return a string. So if you need to sum up integer values - you have to parse them first. Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) depending on the type of values.

**UPDATE:** you may see the working example with some fake data (with parsing numbers) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kBB4A/).

Comment: Kiril - thank you for taking a stab at this.  Sadly, the solution didn't work - I got a javascript error on the var names = Object line.

Comment: @nashleigh, I updated the code. Seems that you use rather old browser. Anyway, with my updates it should work perfect.

Comment: @nashleigh, also, I'm not sure if the loop `for(x=1;x<=opt.length-1;x++) {` is correct. Maybe `for(x=1;x<=opt.options.length-1;x++) {`?

Comment: Thanks Kiril - works like a charm.  And yes, I have to work with IE9.  I appreciate the help...!!